# Mockito Mock run Autowired class Object

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, springmockito

I have below class scenario. While testing MyTestableClass, I wish to process Autowired class.
I would like to mock only variable in AutoWired class.

sample class is as below-

```
public class MyTestableClass {

    @Autowired
    private MyServiceClass service;

    public void handleError(){
    ...
    service.doSomething();

    }
}

public class MyServiceClass {

    @Autowired
    private JMSChannel channel;

    public void doSomething(){
        System.out.println("Inside Service class");
        .....
        channel.isAvailable();
        .....   
    }
}

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class  MyTestableClassTest {
    private MyTestableClass  testClass= new MyTestableClass();

    private JMSChannel channel;

    @Before
    public void init(){
     channel= mock(JMSChannel.class);
     when(channel.isAvailable()).thenReturn(Boolean.TRUE);  
    }

    @Test
    public void test(){
        testClass.handleError();
    }
}
```

For example, Console should give me "Inside Service class" before returning true.

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: +1, How do I create an instance of Autowired service? I don't want to mock it, so as to get into doSomething(). Thanks!

Comment: Ideally, move from field injection to constructor injection, then just pass the mock to the constructor.

Comment: @chrylis, may I ask for example/code?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create and instance of your service (or a mock of it) and set its channel to your mocked one, then set `MyTestableClass#service` to this one. Something like:

```
@Before
public void init(){
    channel= mock(JMSChannel.class);
    when(channel.isAvailable()).thenReturn(Boolean.TRUE); 
    MyServiceClass service = new MyServiceClass();
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(service, "channel", channel);
    myTestableClass = new MyTestableClass();
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(myTestableClass, "service", service);
}
```

with `ReflectionTestUtils` from [spring-test](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/util/ReflectionTestUtils.html) (**NB:** you can use a setter instead)

Comment: Mockito comes with the [Whitebox](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/internal/util/reflection/Whitebox.html) class which does basically the same thing as ReflectionTestUtils

Comment: I get exception " java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Couldn not find field [channel] of type [null] on target [MyServiceClass]" while running this testcase.

Comment: This is not a ready to use by copy paste answer, just a starting point / explanation. I did edit out a mistake that might explain your error.